# How to convert any value from sql table into string

Tags: php, mysqli

There is some data is stored in my sql table. I want to fetch the data in the form of string.

```
$sql= "SELECT hash FROM signupinfo WHERE fname = 'nikhil';";
$hashfix = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
echo $hashfix;
```

but the error coming

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\localhost\webroot\signup.php on line 48

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($hashfix). If you want to read your array all Data fetched from a db come in the form of array

Its not a good idea to echo array...by that I mean you can't.  What you can do in to make a string is. $a=implode(',',$hashfix)

There are 2 ways to print values you want

If its a single key array.
echo $hashfix[0]->ColumnName

Or run a foreach

Comment: Updated check new content tell me if this is what you need

Comment: this output the value in the form of                                                              object `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`  i want the value in string for example any name  (like nikhil) or any hash value

Comment: Your selecting hash

Comment: If you want fname select fname. If you want all data. Then select * where fname =nikhil

Comment: Print using  echo $hashfix['fname']

Comment: i try `implode (',',$hashfix)` it says `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\localhost\webroot\signup.php on line 49`

Comment: Ohh and use mysqli_result()

Comment: the sql query returns a recordset object, not an array so you can't simply `implode`

Comment: mysqli_result($connection,$sql);

Comment: please write full code how i can output any table field value as it is.

Comment: Opps I meant explode(',',$hashfix);    explode makes arrays string

Comment: mysqli_store_result()  or try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
$sql= "SELECT `hash` FROM `signupinfo` WHERE `fname` = 'nikhil';";
$hashfix = mysqli_query( $connection, $sql ); 
if( $hashfix ){
    while( $rs=$connection->fetch_object( $hashfix ) ){
        echo $rs->hash;
    }
}
```